# Sorting Routeboxer results

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to sort the array that is returned from Routeboxer? In addition to displaying markers along a route, I also display the marker locations in a list, and I want the list sorted by distance (closest from origin to farthest). However, Routeboxer seems to return the array sorted by latitude (?).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to sort the result manually. The [Routeboxer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/docs/examples.html) sorting is intentional so that the route is preserved, beginning at the origin and ending at the destination to give you the bounds boxes of the route itself.

For information on sorting the arrays see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects).